# Making a method for swaping two int's position within an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Anyone give me any insight as why the following snippet of code gives a cannot find symbol error,
 this swap() should be used as when given an array list name it will swap the contents of index location 1 with location 2

Cheers!

```
public static void swap(String swapArray, int location1, int location2) {
    int tempswap1 = swapArray.get(location1);
    int tempswap2 = swapArray.get(location2);
    swapArray.set(location1)=tempswap2;
    swapArray.set(location2)=tempswap1;
}
```

Comment: `swapArray` is not an `ArrayList`, it is a `String`. In Java, `String`s are immutable (cannot be modified).

Answer (score 1):

**Cause for error:**

```
swapArray.set(location1)

swapArray.get(location1)
```

Since `swapArray`  is a `String` type, there in no `set` method  and even `get` method in `String` class.

**Possible resolution:**

If I'm not wrong,  `swapArray`  should be `List` type. Please check and as a side note use an `IDE`  like Eclipse which saves you lot of time.

Might useful further :

- [Arraylist swap elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963549/arraylist-swap-elements)

**Update:**

```
    public static void swap(List swapArray, int location1, int location2) {
-------------------------------^
        int tempswap1 = swapArray.get(location1);
        int tempswap2 = swapArray.get(location2);
        swapArray.set(location1,tempswap2);
        swapArray.set(location2,tempswap1);
    }
```

Assuming you are passing a list to swap method.

Comment: The swapArray is used to enter the name of arraylist which i would like to swap, as there is multiple, how would use the users data with out using a string to achieve this, Thanks!

Comment: @DavidMcDaid   Your method signature is wrong, updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `swapArray` is of type list as mentioned in your question title, you need to swap the values like this

```
swapArray.set(location1, tempswap2); // Set the location1 with value2
swapArray.set(location2, tempswap1); // Set the location2 with value1
```

The error is because of `swapArray.set(location1)=tempswap2;`. The left hand side is a method call(`set()`) which returns a value and you are trying to assign another value to a value, which is illegal. You need to have a variable on the LHS of the assignment operator.

---

Also, this should be/have been the actual method signature

```
public static void swap(List<Integer> swapArray, int location1, int location2)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - This is the type of the object you're passing. You needn't give the name of that object as such.
```

---

**Side Note:** Always remember to copy/paste the code from the IDE, instead of manually typing it here, as you tend to make typos and syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick you can use here

```
public static <T> void swap(List<T> list, int pos1, int pos2) {
    list.set(pos1, list.set(pos2, list.get(pos1)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String are immutable in Java. You can't change them.
You need to create a new string with the character replaced.
Check this thread:
[Replace a character at a specific index in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/java-replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

I like Peter's answer better.  But if you were just putting your Strings in a collection for purposes of calling setters (that don't exist anyway) you can do it all with native code.

Keep in mind that if you're doing a lot of String manipulation you should use a StringBuffer if you need thread safety or a StringBuilder if your program is not multi-threaded.  Because as mentioned Strings are actually immutable - meaning every time you change one you are actually destroying the old object and creating a new one.

This code would need to be a little smarter if the starting point (e.g. loc1) could be offset 0, but the general idea for native String manipulation is:

```
String x = a.substring(loc1,loc1+1);
String y = b.substring(loc2,loc2+1);
a = a.substring(0, loc1) + y + a.substring(loc1);
b = b.substring(0,loc2) + x + b.substring(loc2);
```