# Moving around items in an ArrayList

Tags: java

Lets say I have an ArrayList name list

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6
```

How would I do this:
Move Item 2 to index 3

```
Item 1
Item 3
Item 4
Item 2
Item 5
Item 6
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963549/arraylist-swap-elements

Comment: Did you try to do anything yet?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collections.swap` if you know the index of elements you wish to swap

```
Collections.swap(list,i,j);
```

And you can get the index of an element using `list.indexOf(element)` if you don't know the index

Comment: A single `swap` call wouldn't be enough here; multiple items are changing place.

Comment: @yshavit aren't the elements being swapped?

Comment: @yshavit sorry, you are right. But my answer doesn't specify how many swaps you need :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the item to any position in the list using `set` method, however, it would overwrite the existing item, to perform a swap, we can do the following:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
System.out.println(list);
String element0 = list.get(0);
String element1 = list.get(1);
list.set(0, element1);
list.set(1, element0);
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: What if the length of the list is unknown?

Comment: We can check the length of the list with `size()` method.