# error: swap(Object[],int,int) has private access in Collections

Tags: java, collections, compiler-errors

I am learning Java and coding up the `QuickSort` class. At some point one needs to swap elements in the array, so I am trying to do that with the `Collections.swap`, which is recommended, for instance, [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963549/arraylist-swap-elements). However, `javac QuickSort.java` throws an error at me:

`error: swap(Object[],int,int) has private access in Collections`

What am I doing wrong here? Complete code of `QuickSort.java`:

```
package src.sort;

import java.util.Collections;

public class QuickSort {
    public static void sort(Comparable[] xs) {
        sort(xs, 0, xs.length);
    }

    private static boolean less(Comparable x, Comparable y) {
        return x.compareTo(y) < 0;
    }

    private static void sort(Comparable[] xs, int fst, int lst) {
        if (fst >= lst) return;

        int i = fst, j = lst;

        Comparable pivot = xs[(i + j) / 2];

        while (i <= j) {
            while (less(xs[i++], pivot));
            while (less(pivot, xs[j--]));

            if (i <= j) Collections.swap(xs, i++, j--);
        }

        sort(xs, fst, j);
        sort(xs, i, lst);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is quite explicit. You can't call that method, since it's a private method, accessible only be code within the `Collections` class. It's easy enough to write your own method that would have the same functionality as this simple method.

The swap method recommended in the linked question is a public method that swaps two elements of a List - `public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j)`. The method you tried to call is a different method, that swaps two elements of an array, and it's private - `private static void swap(Object[] arr, int i, int j)`.

Comment: How come then it is used in [the question I linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963549/arraylist-swap-elements?lq=1)?

Comment: @all3fox `swap(List<?> list, int i, int j);` is public while `swap(Object[] arr, int i, int j)` is private.